# Variable concatenation and manipulation in u-boot

Tags: u-boot

I am trying to create a variable eth1addr in u-boot (ver=U-Boot 2020.04-5.7.0-devel+git.33bb8e968332).

I have a variable ethaddr available in u-boot. ethaddr contains a MAC address (e.g. AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF).

I have a custom OUI (e.g 11:22:33)

I want to set the value of eth1addr to the custom OIU in the first three bytes, and in the last three bytes I want to copy the last three bytes of ethaddr.

So, with the examples above this would give me eth1addr=11:22:33:DD:EE:FF.
I do not want to hardcode eth1addr. I want to derive it from the value ethaddr.